# Import many .SQL files at once

Tags: mysql, macos

I am new to Mac OS.  I have installed navicat and sequel pro.
I have a MySQL database copy dumped to about 100 .sql files (one for each table.)

I want to import them to my localhost newly created DB.
How can I do this with Navicat or Sequel Pro?

There is only information about importing one file at once...

Comment: I don't know about Navicat and Sequel Pro, but from the command line one could simply do `mysql -u Username -pPassword < *.sql`.

Comment: You can also try combining them into one file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd combine them as @tadman mentioned into one file using the terminal.  If all your files are in `~/Documents/sql` as an example...

`cat ~/Documents/sql/*.sql > complete.sql`

Then use mysql to import them:

`mysql -u [MySQL_USER] -p [DBNAME_TO_IMPORT_INTO] < ~/Documents/sql/complete.sql`

**OR**, all in one step as @eggyal mentioned

`mysql -u [MySQL_USER] -p [DBNAME_TO_IMPORT_INTO] < ~/Documents/sql/*.sql`

You'll be prompted for your MySQL password in both cases but either should do the trick.  If you don't want to use the terminal to import into MySQL the file made with `cat` above can be imported with either Navicat or Sequel Pro.